# Include referenced table via LINQ under MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

How I can use `Include` of the LINQ properly under MVC3?

I created **.edmx** file and it has all tables.

Two of them have a relashionships

> UserCategories 1..0 - * Users

I guessed to use

```
var userCategories = db.UserCategories.Include("Users");
```

in order to populate `Users` property. ***But it is always empty***.

([Here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4) there is a good example how to use it. But no success.)

How do I can fix it?

**P.S. POCO class**

```
 public partial class UserCategory
    {
        public UserCategory()
        {
            this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public System.Guid ID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: @Jorge How I can do it? I am not sure if I have it at all.

Comment: Asuming that you're using entity framework check your .tt file

Comment: @Jorge Yep. Done. Could have a look at it pls?

Comment: As I know, Since there is a relationship between user categories and users we can use include. Also we can access the connected tables using navigation properties as well. As I think db is your entity framework reference.

Comment: @Diode Correct. I know it. But somehow Users is empty. What I know that is under RIA services I can use [Include] attribute. And it works fine together with .Include("EntityName") of LINQ. But how do I can realize it for MVC3 ?

Comment: If you want to see the values of the users as well, you have to use it inside a foreach, for each item, item.Users.[column Name you want]. I do not know weather I am miss leading you. But this worked for me.

Comment: Are you expecting to pass a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first if `Users` it's empty probably it's because your don't have the data in the database. Now to be specific refactor your expression like this

```
var userCategories = db.UserCategories.Select(x => x.Users).ToList();
```

This will retrieve all the users in your database which have a relation with the table UserCategory

If you just tried to obtain the users no matter the relation with the table

```
var users = db.Users.ToList(); // This retrieve all the users in your database
```

Disclaimer: note that this expressions are heave and bring all the records of your database used carefully

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Model
{
   private int userName;
   .....
   public UserName{get{return userName;} set{userName= value;}}
   ....
}
```

I am assuming that Model is the passing model and it has a UserName attribute. And there is a userName column in Users Table.

```
    private dbContext db = new dbContext();

    public List<Model> method(){
    List<Model> m= List<Model>()   
    var userCategories = db.UserCategories.Include("Users");

    return from item in userCategories select new Model
             {
                 UserName = item.Users.userName
                 .......
             }
    }
```

This return value will be a `IEnumerable<Model>` it will be executed in foreach. So the